# Facerecognizer with opencv 2.4.5

Tags: eclipse, opencv, face-recognition

I am working o the face recognition example at : http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/modules/contrib/doc/facerec/tutorial/facerec_video_recognition.html. 
I am using eclipse on ubuntu if thats relevant. Earlier I was using 2.3.1 but it came with an error  `‘FaceRecognizer’ was not declared in this scope` so after going through the reply here https://stackoverflow.com/a/11399099/824239 I updated to the  version 2.4.5 of opencv on a different path, but previous version of opencv is still on the machine. Now after directing my include path and libraries to the new location in the eclipse project, I am still getting the same error.

```
make all 
Building file: ../src/faceRec_vid.cpp
Invoking: GCC C++ Compiler
g++ -I/usr/local/research/opencv/include/opencv2 -I/usr/local/research/opencv/include/opencv -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -MMD -MP -MF"src/faceRec_vid.d" -MT"src/faceRec_vid.d" -o"src/faceRec_vid.o" "../src/faceRec_vid.cpp"
../src/faceRec_vid.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, const char**)’:
../src/faceRec_vid.cpp:87:9: error: ‘FaceRecognizer’ was not declared in this scope
../src/faceRec_vid.cpp:87:23: error: template argument 1 is invalid
../src/faceRec_vid.cpp:87:31: error: invalid type in declaration before ‘=’ token
../src/faceRec_vid.cpp:87:60: error: ‘createFisherFaceRecognizer’ was not declared in this scope
../src/faceRec_vid.cpp:88:10: error: base operand of ‘->’ is not a pointer
../src/faceRec_vid.cpp:118:39: warning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions [-Wsign-compare]
../src/faceRec_vid.cpp:136:35: error: base operand of ‘->’ is not a pointer
make: *** [src/faceRec_vid.o] Error 1
```

Am I missing any thing that i need to do to direct my eclipse project to the right version. How can I get rid of this error.

Answer (score 0):

You said you have "updated" to 2.4.5 but OpenCV 2.3.1 still existing means you have installed 2.4.5 on a different path. You got the same errors because you have not configured eclipse properly to use the OpenCV 2.4.5 library. your /usr/local/lib seems to have 2.3.1 so(shared object) files and since you have not asked eclipse to link the new libraries, (no -l passed with g++) it's linked with the old libraries by default.

To do that,
Go to **Project-->Properties**.

Expand **GCC C++ Linker** and click on **Libraries**.

In the **Library search path (-L)**, fill in the path where you have installed OpenCV2.4.5.

Then in **Libraries(-l)** add the OpenCV libraries that you may need (opencv_core opencv_imgproc opencv_highgui)

Comment: I have already done that. the library search Path is directed to the opencv2.4.5 libraries.

Comment: @UmairR. Then why is `g++` called with out any -l or -L to the opencv libraries?. Did you try compiling the `faceRec_vid.cpp` file from the command line using `g++ -I/usr/local/research/opencv/include/opencv2 -I/usr/local/research/opencv/include/opencv -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -L$OPENCVLIBS_DIR -o"src/faceRec_vid.o" "../src/faceRec_vid.cpp"`.  Where $OPENCVLIBS_DIR is the directory where the linker can find the opencv2.4.5 libraries.

Comment: You have a valid poitn here, but I dont know why is it(eclipse) not calling the -l or -L options. Anyways even with the above command as you said I am getting exactly the same error.

Answer (score 0):

You probably solved this by now, but if you haven't this was my solution. 
I came accross this problem when i tried the tutorial code myself. You need to include `<opencv2/contrib/contrib.hpp>`. Hope that helps.